# integration of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{n(x+\pi)}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{m(x+\pi)}{2})dx$

Tags: integration

I'm working on solving the integration 
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{n(x+\pi)}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{m(x+\pi)}{2})dx$ and my results after using the integration by parts for different cases for the integers $n$ and $m$ as the following:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{n(x+\pi)}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{m(x+\pi)}{2})dx=
\begin{cases}
0,& \text{for } n\neq m \& (n-m)^2\neq4,\\
0,& \text{for } n=m\neq1,\\
\frac{1}{2},& \text{for }n=m=1,\\
-\frac{1}{2},& \text{for } (n-m)^2=4. \\
\end{cases}
$$
Is there any way to make sure I have the correct results?
appreciate any help:)

here is a case when $n=m\neq1:$

using the identity:
$sin(A)sin(B)=\frac{1}{2}[cos(A-B)-cos(A+B)]$
I get:$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{n(x+\pi)}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{m(x+\pi)}{2})dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(x)cos(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))-cos(x)cos(\frac{n+m}{2}(x+\pi))dx$

using the integration by parts twice for the first term:

$\begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(x)cos(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))dx&=[\frac{2}{n-m}cos(x)sin(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))]_{-\pi}^{\pi}+\frac{2}{n-m}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(x)sin(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))dx\\&=(\frac{1}{(1-\frac{4}{(n-m)^2})})\bigg[[\frac{2}{n-m}cos(x)sin(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))]_{-\pi}^{\pi}-\frac{4}{(n-m)^2}[sin(x)cos(\frac{n-m}{2}(x+\pi))]_{-\pi}^{\pi}\bigg]\\&=0.\end{align}$

Similarly for the other term:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(x)cos(\frac{n+m}{2}(x+\pi))dx=0$

Hence for $n=m\neq1:$

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{n(x+\pi)}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\sin(\frac{m(x+\pi)}{2})dx=0$

Comment: Could you please show how you got your answer for at least one of the cases? This way we would be able to follow up on any mistakes you made throughout and can prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: sure, I will edit a case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$2\sin\frac{n(x+\pi)}2\sin\frac{m(x+\pi)}2=\cos\frac{(n-m)(x+\pi)}2-\cos\frac{(n+m)(x+\pi)}2$$ and \begin{align}2\cos\frac{(n\pm m)(x+\pi)}2\cos x&=\cos\frac{(n\pm m)(x+\pi)-x}2+\cos\frac{(n\pm m)(x+\pi)+x}2\\&=\cos\frac{(n\pm m-1)x+(n\pm m)\pi}2+\cos\frac{(n\pm m+1)x+(n\pm m)\pi}2\end{align} so $$\cos x\sin\frac{n(x+\pi)}2\sin\frac{m(x+\pi)}2\\=\\\frac14\left[\left(\cos\frac{(n-m-1)x+(n-m)\pi}2+\cos\frac{(n-m+1)x+(n-m)\pi}2\right)-\left(\cos\frac{(n+m-1)x+(n+m)\pi}2+\cos\frac{(n+m+1)x+(n+m)\pi}2\right)\right].$$ Thus $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos x\sin\frac{n(x+\pi)}2\sin\frac{m(x+\pi)}2\,dx=\frac12\left[\frac{\sin\frac{(n-m-1)x+(n-m)\pi}2}{n-m-1}+\frac{\sin\frac{(n-m+1)x+(n-m)\pi}2}{n-m+1}-\frac{\sin\frac{(n+m-1)x+(n+m)\pi}2}{n+m-1}-\frac{\sin\frac{(n+m+1)x+(n+m)\pi}2}{n+m+1}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi=\frac12\left[\frac{\sin\frac{(2(n-m)-1)\pi}2}{n-m-1}+\frac{\sin\frac{(2(n-m)+1)\pi}2}{n-m+1}-\frac{\sin\frac{(2(n+m)-1)\pi}2}{n+m-1}-\frac{\sin\frac{(2(n+m)+1)\pi}2}{n+m+1}\right]-\frac12\left[\frac{1}{n-m-1}-\frac{1}{n-m+1}-\frac{1}{n+m-1}+\frac{1}{n+m+1}\right]$$ ...

Comment: $ -(-(-(-1)))$...

Comment: Thank you TheSimpliFire  this is really helpful:)

Comment: No problem. Though I haven't yet had the time to check your work, I see you've made some good progress :)

Comment: Yep, but my results are completely different from yours :( by the way what is the case when $n-m=1$ the first two terms are undefined!

Comment: This is rather interesting... you've used integration by parts twice on $\cos x\cos\frac{(n+m)(x+\pi)}2$ whereas I continued with the trigonometric splitting and turned it into a standard integral. I'm not currently sure why they're different (if they are) but I'll look into more detail later.